# changes to og:image values are not updated in Disqus recommendations

Tags: facebook-opengraph, disqus

I recently enabled post recommendation for my disqus account on my site. The recommendations work mostly except, I recently changed the open graph image value for that post. But this is not being reflected in the post preview of the recommendations.

For example check this post. https://springhow.com/spring-boot-pdf-generation/

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Is there are way to refresh this value? Also I tried [submitting the issue to the disqus forum](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/channel-discussdisqus/embed_images_are_not_updated_in_recommendations/). But no help there as well.